# Unexpected result when testing conditional: checks if inputs starts with 0 or ends with numbers

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I am trying to learn Python, and in this context I work on a problem.
The problem aims to check if a string of characters:

- contains 2 characters at minimim and 6 at miximum
- starts with 2 letters
- if containing numbers, these arrive at the end of the string
- the numbers do not start with a 0
- no ponctuation is used in the string

From what I understand, only two parts of the code are causing the issue, I am hence presenting these two issues only:

My code is as follows:

```
def number_end_plate(s):
    if s.isalpha():
        return False
    else:
       number = ""
       for char in s:
           if char.isnumeric():
               number = number + char
           else:
               number = number
           result = number.startswith("0")
           return(result)

# Function "number_end_plate" checks if the numbers starts with zero. If "True" then this will be rejected in the above function

def numbers_after_letter(s):
    if s.isalpha():
        return True
    elif len(s) == 4 and s == s[3:4].isnumeric():
         return True
    elif len(s) == 4 and s == s[3:3].isalpha() and s == s[4:4].isnumeric():
         return True
    elif len(s) == 5 and s == s[3:5].isnumeric():
         return True
    elif len(s) == 5 and s == s[3:4].isalpha() and s == s[5:5].isnumeric():
         return True
    elif len(s) == 5 and s == s[3:3].isalpha() and s == s[4:5].isnumeric():
         return True
    elif len(s) == 6 and s == s[3:6].isnumeric():
        return True
    elif len(s) == 6 and s == s[3:3].isalpha() and s == s[4:6].isnumeric():
        return True
    elif len(s) == 6 and s == s[3:4].isalpha() and s == s[5:6].isnumeric():
        return True
    elif len(s) == 6 and s == s[3:5].isalpha() and s == s[6:6].isnumeric():
        return True

#Function checks if the numbers (if any) are always at the end of the string
```

I am failing the following tests, I do not understand why I get "`Invalid`" as a result:

- AK88
- ECZD99
- IKLMNV

Comment: `number_end_plate == False and numbers_after_letter == False` ... You're not calling the functions.

Comment: In the future, please make a [mre], which can help catch basic mistakes like that. For more tips, check out [ask].

Comment: How is the question not meeting the point defined in this page? The minimum amount of code is provided, along with the test case leading to issues? No?

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out the mistake of not calling the function `tnumber_end_plate == False and numbers_after_letter == False` however, after correcting this the test still fail.

Comment: Minimum amount of code? This code checks 5 conditions, but you're only having a problem with 2, so the other 3 aren't relevant. **edit**: Oh, you changed the title, making it less clear.

Comment: Thank you! I understand...My goal when editing the title was to make it clearer, not less clear. I am sorry this caused frustration on your side. I do not know what conditions are making this not relevant, or what points may impact the output, this is why I shared what I shared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257053/discussion-between-elvino-michel-and-wjandrea).

Comment: Ah OK, so then you should try testing the functions in isolation, e.g. `assert starts_alpha("ECZD99")` or `assert not starts_alpha("99ECZD")`.

Comment: Many thanksI I did not know about "assert_starts_alpha". Until know I mostly tried to test my code by writing a high number of "pint" statement. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, there's a lot you can do to clean up your code, e.g. in `is_valid`: `return lenght_valid(s) and ... and not number_end_plate(s) and ...` and in `lenght_valid`: `return 2 <= len(s) <= 6`

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I am not sure I understand, but I will also try to digest this input.

Comment: I removed the code that as per my understanding was not usefull, and reverted to the older title to make things clearer @wjandrea. I hope this helps. I really try to not be a pain, I am sorry if I caused frustration. Thank you for your pointers.

Comment: Thank you @Jan. I have not started learning regular expression however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has many issues and inconsistencies, but the answer to your question lies in this function:

```
def number_end_plate(s):
    if s.isalpha():
        return False
    else:
       number = ""
       for char in s:
           if char.isnumeric():
               number = number + char
           else:
               number = number
           result = number.startswith("0")
           return(result)
```

The return statement is indented inside the for loop, so it will only ever iterate once. It's also unclear what it is supposed to check. Seemingly that the plate ends in a number, but you use it like this: `and number_end_plate(s) == False` - so, apparently a plat that ends in a number should always be invalid?

That doesn't match the description you provided. You then have a very complicated function that supposedly checks if all the numbers are at the end of the string.

Other issues with your code include spacing (both vertical space between code, and the much worse inconsistent indentation), spelling errors (in names), inconsistency in how your functions work (sometimes being terse and returning a result directly, other times wordy if-statements), and perhaps more logic errors beyond what I indicated above.

Fixing those, but keeping the overall structure of your program (which is still very verbose), you'd end up with something like this:

```
import string


def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    return valid_length(s) and starts_alpha(s) and no_punctuation(s) and number_end_plate(s)


def valid_length(s):
    return 2 <= len(s) <= 6


def starts_alpha(s):
    return s[0:2].isalpha()


def no_punctuation(s):
    return not any(character in string.punctuation for character in s)


def number_end_plate(s):
    found_number = False
    for ch in s:
        if ch.isdigit():
            if not found_number:
                if ch == '0':
                    # the first number cannot be a 0
                    return False
            found_number = True
        else:
            if found_number:
                # if there's something that's not a number after a number
                return False
    # at this point, the text is valid
    return True


main()
```

Edit: you asked how `number_end_plate(s)` works exactly, here's a line by line explanation with comments:

```
def number_end_plate(s):
    # found_number represents whether we've found any number so far
    # it starts `False` because we haven't found one yet
    found_number = False

    # `ch` will go over every character in `s`
    for ch in s:
        # if we run into a digit (0-9) ...
        if ch.isdigit():
            # then, if we haven't found a number yet ...
            if not found_number:
                # then, if the number we found is a zero ...
                if ch == '0':
                    # then the first number is a zero, and that's not allowed
                    return False  # this stops the execution, and returns False

            # in any case, if we keep going, remember we found a number
            found_number = True
        else:
            # otherwise (if `ch` is not a digit),
            # if we previously found a number
            if found_number:
                # then, this means there's 'not a number' after a number
                return False

    # if we get here, we've looped through all characters without returning False
    # that means none of the conditions we were looking for arose
    # and the string is valid for the condition that numbers are at then end
    # and the first number is not a 0 (or there are no numbers at all)
    return True
```

Comment: You mentioned *that supposedly checks if all the numbers are at the end of the string.* yes exactly. This what I am trying to do. If at the end of the string, I have a mix of letter and numbers, then it is wrong. You mentioned that I am quite verbose. Do you have advice to improve this?

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I realize that I strongly struggle to understand this complicated function. But it does work. I do not understand it however.

Comment: [**`^(?=\D+\d*$)[a-z]{2}[a-z1-9]{0,4}$`**](https://regex101.com/r/aR0Pqb/1) is *a lot* easier :-)

Comment: Ok here is my understanding so far. You start a function, which starts by "being" false.  If you find a number equal to zero you return return "False". This is what I tried in my first function. Then you start with you "else" and if  you found a number ...it is false? Why?

Comment: Maybe @Jan but this is currently really outside of my "brain power" so to speak. I must first master the basic, which apparently I clearly do not.

Comment: @ElvinoMichel: Again, no worries. Grasp the idea of Grismar's functionality (but don't use it in "real life").

Comment: Thank you @Jan! I will try to finally understand.... hopefully in the next hour because it is already late...

Comment: I'll add some explanation to that function.

Comment: Have a read of the comments I added as explanation before each line. Also, keep a close eye on the indentation. When nesting `if` statements like these, you have to pay close attention to that. This is why it's important to use a consistent indent size (4 spaces is standard and recommended). You'll find that reading the structure of a program like that becomes second nature very quickly - but if these types of structures go on for too long, it can be better to break them up into something more readable. I chose this mainly to stay close to your original code.

Comment: Thank you again, this is really detailed, and really helpful. This is honestly a challenge for me. I wonder if this is normal to have so many difficulties wrapping my head around this.

Comment: Don't worry - different people struggle with different parts. Learning to program means learning a large number of small things all at once, and if you only miss a few, the whole thing doesn't work. If you end up with code as long and complicated as the function I basically eliminated from your code though, you should probably generally lean back and wonder if there's a simpler approach. I see what you were trying to do there, but clearly the problem isn't as complicated as you made it out to be. A solution doesn't have to be beautiful, but "just working" is a very low bar.

Comment: Also note that your question received a lot of comments, no down-votes and no votes to close it. That's a good sign that people take your question seriously. It's not a dumb question, even if there's a lot to be said about the code when compared to the 'ideal'.